# Switch between NSView

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I have an NSView with two views inside of it. I am trying to hide one view and show the other one, but the view won't change.

I tried with setHidden, removeFromSuperview, addSubview in front, everything. The first view is still there and the other one will not show itself. I am doing something wrong?

Thank you,
—Albé

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as each of the sub views has a connection to it (`IBOutlet`) then you should be able to use `[superView replaceSubview:oldView with:newView];`.

Comment: Oh. You're right. I thought the connections were fine, but I connected the same Outlet with two subviews. Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to retain both views (e.g., with a retaining property). If you don't have accessors for each outlet, the nib loader will simply assign the views' pointers to the outlet ivars, and one of the views will die the moment you remove it from the view hierarchy, leading to a crash later on.

Comment: i have connected the two NSView object to 2 outlets. but i cant seem to access this superview directly.. [[[self window] superView] replaceSubview:view1 with:view2] is not working..!! any help would be welocme

Comment: That's the wrong direction to travel in the view hierarchy. try `[[view1 superview] replaceSubview:view1 with:view2];` Currently you are trying to get the window's superview, which doesn't exist as it is the root view.

Answer (score 3):

### Switch between viewOne and viewTwo :

#### First add the view to primary view

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self.view addSubview:self.viewOne];
}
```

#### Replace Subview

```
[self.view replaceSubview:self.viewOne with:self.viewTwo];
```

### With Animation :

Select your container view, and check it in **Core Animation Layer**, next choose a transition below.

[image]

#### Switch view with animation :

```
[[self.view animator] replaceSubview:self.viewOne with:self.viewTwo];
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to theMikeSwan's suggestion, you could use NSViewAnimation (or a host of other techniques) to animate the transition.

Answer (score 1):

You could also put both views into a tabless tab view, and simply set the selected tab index of the tab view.